Pointcut expression not working for inherited methods
I have this pointcut expression:
@Around(
  "execution(public * com.my.service.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.*(String,..)) && " +
  "args(nodePath, ..)"
)

It works for methods that have been overridden or are new in the class, but not for inherited methods that haven’t been overridden.
I checked the examples mentioned in the AspectJ Programming Guide (Language Semantics, Pointcuts) and believe that inherited methods should work if they satisfy the argument condition. However, the advice is not being applied to such methods. If I override the method in my class, the advice works on them. Is there something I’m missing?

If you checked the example, what exactly makes you assume that it works like you think it should? Can you please provide an MCVE reproducing your problem, ideally on GitHub? I am not sure, if I understand your problem correctly.

I was able to solve the issue by using
@Around("bean(defaultRepositoryService) && args(nodePath, ..)")

Well, the way your question is phrased, missing a reproducible example, and not having an answer because you simply mentioned a non-verifiable, local solution you found by yourself in a terse comment, the question is not worth anything to future readers. I suggest to simply delete it, if you are too lazy to extend the question and write a comprehensive answer. Thank you very much.
